# How to reach ~50nA p-p current noise in ~200mA current source?

Tags: noise, current-source, constant-current, ldo

Target application is driving single-frequency laser diodes (@2.5V) which are sensitive to current noise. Current is constant, with no modulation.

Strightforward solutions that first comes to mind is low-noise LDO (for example LT1963) that can reach ~40µV RMS which would give us around 4µA RMS of current noise. TPS7A4700 is better at 4µV RMS, which will give us ~400nA of RMS noise. But that is still far away from 50nA p-p.

Could the rest of the gap be covered by filtering / capacitance multipliers? Or there are specific solutions to low-noise current sources that are significantly better than high-end LDO?

Comment: which bandwidth does your voltage source needs to have (i.e. what's the highest frequency of the current drawn from it), and at what temperatures can you operate? Thing about noise is that you can rarely bound peaks; you can bound variance (i.e. RMS) of the noise, as the underlying probability density functions tend to have infinite support.

Comment: I would expect 1Hz could be a good cut-off for frequency response, but maybe even 0.1Hz is possible to work with. Laser diode properties / IV curve change with temperature, but it is regulated to +-0.01°C, so it can be assumed it does not really change. 0.1Hz should be enough for any long-term effects. Electronics work at 25+-5°C.

Comment: The first question that arose to mind, before I'd finished the first sentence, is the one that Marcus asked -- bandwidth. But reading the rest I wonder how anyone could hope to help you identify the dominant source (there's ever only one or two of them to worry over at any given level of experimental control over the *known* variables) with so little information to go on about the system setup or what experiments have been designed and then performed in order to validate earlier assumptions going into the project.

Comment: @jonk At the moment I am interested in approaches to design low-noise current sources, not in complete device performance in specific experiment. Surely all that will have to be dealt with at the end during practical tests. My current system has 3-5µA RMS current noise, and resulting frequency noise of the laser diode is measurable with very significant margin (I think even system performance with 300nA noise should be measurable with current approach). But surely this does not tell what is the source of the noise.

Comment: @BarsMonster I'll take your point. You have an exclusive, narrow interest in exactly and no more than you presented in your question. Accepted. I'm no longer interested as there are much better people at this kind of question than I am.

Comment: I would consider negative feedback on the laser output  to a PD that is tightly coupled to side leakage to regulate the current with a wide BW.  But the PD & voltage reference needs serious shielding for laser diode noise reduction.  But you need a phase noise spec as the oscillations can be in the GHz.  The success of your design depends on your ability to define the phase noise specs and stability of each component in feedback along reference noise and  stray positive feedback determining your SNR. https://www.rp-photonics.com/noise_specifications.html

Comment: https://www.rp-photonics.com/article_noise_in_laser_technology1.html

Comment: @jonk Sorry if I sounded harsh - there was no intent. Stackexchange sites steers all discussion into such narrow & strict questions, otherwise questions are often closed as off-topic...

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Amplitude noise of laser emission is not a concern. I've tried using internal PD for optical feedback, but it made frequency noise worse. That might be expected: PD signal is weak and by definition is much more noisy. At the same time, we have full "visibility" of all electronics going through diode by measuring / stabilizing current. Laser diode optical frequency noise that I am observing now is ~50Mhz, and my intention is to lower it.

Comment: @BarsMonster Your excuse is what you believe about the site. Perhaps that's baggage from prior experiences. I don't work that way, regardless of the site. I focus on what's really at issue and sometimes that requires more information. I don't think the site here would oppose you providing more detail. So I just simply disagree with your assessment and apparent self-censorship (if that's what it is) as a result.

Comment: @BarsMonster Regardless, if all you want to hear at this time is from people who know how to make low noise voltage supplies, then you do NOT want me around. There are really well experienced people in that area. And, likely, more whitepapers than you have time to read, too. Those folks can help you there.

Comment: @BarsMonster The place I may be of some help is when you've exhausted this path and found it wanting. But until then, I say have at it. And if it works for you, then there's no need for more. Go with it.

Comment: @BarsMonster What is your loading current?

Comment: @VoltageSpike 200mA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main theme is: eliminate sources of 1/f as far as possible and limit bandwidth as desired. I suggest the following principal circuit (details added further down):

[image]

**Low Noise Resistor**

The main source of 1/F noise is R1 (at this current level). Therefore, use a resistor with a low *noise index*. This has nothing to do with its value like Johnson noise, but is a material property. Vishay is well known for their ultra-low noise index *"Bulk Metal Foil"* resistors, which are a good fit here. The exact value and tolerance is not so critical, but should be selected to give you 200mA. R1 has to dissipate some power, namely (V1)²/R1. This is one of the reason why the reference voltage should be low. If you don't want the metal foil resistors, take a Wirewound. These are also good when both low noise index and high dissipation are important.

How low a noise index is necessary? You'll have to stay below the 1/f noise of the voltage reference, which is usually around 50 nV/rtHz at 1 Hz (coarse figure). At -40dB Noise Index and a reference voltage of 2.048 V, excess noise at 1 Hz is 13.5 nV/rtHz which would be acceptable. However, if the reference voltage is higher, the excess noise rises proportionally. If you are going for a ~7V buried Zener reference and their slightly lower 1/f noise, you are looking to a resistor with better than -50 dB already. This is ambitious ( your typical low noise precision thin film resistor will be in the -30 dB pallpark. Only use parts which have the noise index actually rated.

**EDIT:** Actually it appears that at such low resistances of well sub 100 Ohm, the Noise Index is less of a problem, [as demonstrated in this excellent and exhaustive study](https://www.dcc.ligo.org/public/0002/T0900200/001/current_noise.pdf). Most parts are well below -40 dB even at 100 Ohms, so lower resistance and higher power will improve this even further. I guess the figures I mentioned above are more usual for ~kOhm sizes resistors.

**Low Drift Reference Voltage**

Then take a high quality voltage reference, with a low voltage, e.g. 1.25 V. The lower voltage will have less internal amplification and less 1/f noise from the reference IC. Most references have a noise rating in ppm of nominal rms. As you want a current with ~0.1 ppm RMS noise, the same goes for the voltage reference. Out-of-the-box all the low noise band gap references are higher than this in the 0.25 ppm to 0.5 ppm ballpark. In order to reach really low peak-to-peak voltage noise with bandgap references, the lowpassing has to be rather strong. 100kOhm + 1000µF are good values as explained at the end. The exact values of R2/C2 and of the reference voltage are only important if you care about the absolute accuracy of the 200 mA. The diode current will be given by V1 / R1. One part that looks appropriate is the LTC6655CHMS8-1.25. As explained below, the 1/f noise of the reference is what will ultimately limit you.

Alternatively, buried Zener types like the LTZ1000 bring lower proportional noise of below 0.2ppm, but they complicate the design considerably (higher voltage, larger R1 needed with even lower noise index, ovenization). The resistor is far more important anyway, so start with a regular reference and it might be good enough.

**Low drift opamp**

Build a voltage follower on the reference voltage using a low drift opamp. As feedback point take the current through the resistor. Most low noise bipolar input opamps have low enough drift and low 1/f noise. Just avoid CMOS input opamps like the plague, unless they include zero-drift circuitry. Infact, the zero-drift CMOS opamps are the best for this job. OPA189 is a good part for this job (zero-drift CMOS).

C1 is not so important, but is a good practise when you have a "long" feedback loop with non-linear parts. Especially because the wires connecting D1, might be indeed physically long and create some inductance. C1 then aids with the opamp stability.

**The pass transistor is not critical at all**

The opamp output steers a pass transistor and this keeps the current through the resistor constant. The pass transistor itself doesn't matter so much. It has to cope with the load current in its linear region. But most of its non-idealities are compensated by the opamp feedback. Any NPN with 0.5A current rating or better will be good. You can use an N-MOSFET too, but you need more voltage at V+ then. Take into account the power dissipation, especially if the V+ is rather high. The pass transistor has to eat all the excess supply voltage.

**Add in the laser diode**

The laser diode will be between the resistor and the pass transistor.

The regulation of the opamp becomes ineffective at around several MHz for typical precision parts. Beyond this frequency, random noise has to be decoupled passively from D1. So let's add in some filtering:

[image]

L1 and C5,6,7 form the main bypass for high frequency noise, with a corner set to ~10 Hz here. You can add more electrolytics to lower the corner frequency further. Typical 10mH chokes rated for a few 100 mA have a series resistance in the 5 Ohm range. This will cause excess noise but this noise is regulated away by the opamp feedback. At higher frequencies above ~MHz, the inductor gets leaky though, due to its winding capacitance. Therefore there is another smaller cap C4 behind the inductor to bypass high frequencies. Together with the impedance R3 it keeps noise up to 100s of MHz away from D1. R3 can be e.g. a ferrite bead generously rated for 0.5 A of higher and can be a normal part with impedance in the ~100 Ohms at a couple of 100 MHz. R3 can also be a resistor. You can use a generic low noise thin film one here. It will have significant excess noise, but this will be regulated away by the opamp feedback. A ferrite bead is probably cheaper and doesn't have to dissipate so much power, and doesn't increase the DC voltage needed to supply the circuit. Finally C3 is the capacitor suggested by you. I don't see much point in it now, but same as C1, it doesn't hurt to have at least footprints for these parts in case they become necessary.

**Powering the circuit**

The power source for the pass transistor and for the opamp (V+) should be not too noisy. Here is where you can use an LDO to supply that power. But I wouldn't use an LDO for the actual precision current output as suggested elsewhere in this topic. The resistors in integrated LDOs are *far* more noisy than good discrete parts. You can also use this LDO to power the reference voltage. The Voltage of V+ should be at least the reference voltage + diode voltage + filter forward drop + 0.7V + some headroom that depends on the pass transistor. A safe value will something like 8-10 V. If you want to use an N-MOSFET instead of the NPN, the replace the 0.7V with whatever is the turn-on voltage of the MOSFET.

**Expected noise performance**

The opamp input current noise does not matter due to the low impedance. Assuming, R1 was selected to have an extremely low noise index and thus negligible 1/f, the two dominating contributions for the peak-to-peak noise are:

1. The wideband input voltage noise of the opamp. It will be about 5nV/rtHz for the OPA189. Divide by R1 to obtain 500pA/rtHz. If you set the cutoff frequency of the L-C-bypass round D1 to about 10 Hz, then this will cause 1.5 nArms or 10 nApp in D1.
2. However, the more important noise voltage comes from the voltage reference.. This is usually about 1uVpp, and this will re-appear entirely over R1. So it will cause 100nApp by itself with R1 at 10 Ohm if left unfiltered. The filtering around D1 does not really help, because this is 1/f noise which hits us right in our target bandwidth. To reach below 50 nApp total noise in D1, the filtering of V1 has to be strong. By tolerating a lengthy run-up time of the circuit of a few minutes, we can set R2 * C2 to 100s which will substantially cut down on the reference voltage noise. To achieve this high RC product, you can set R2 up to 100k, where its Johnson noise will still not matter compared to the low frequency noise of V1. C2 will be 1000 µF which can still be realized using a smallish Al electrolytic cap.

Comment: Wouldn't current noise coming from the opamp be amplified by BJT?

Comment: Yes but due to feedback, it will be regulated away at low frequencies. But it is important that the reference voltage and opamp *inputs* have low 1/f noise. Low noise index of R1 is important because this sets the proportion between 2.5V and the current.

Comment: But higher frequencies in the 10s of MHz+ won't be regulated efficiently, so these should be decoupled passively from the diode. e.g. by placing a ferrite bead in series and a low inductance capacitor in parallel.

Comment: The 100pF feedback capacitor won't be doing much in that design because any feedback is shunted to ground by the 12.5 ohm sense resistor. In order for it to be useful you would need to add a resistor between the sense resistor and the capacitor. This will introduce noise though. However it is almost certainly not needed for stability as the gain of the transistor is less than unity and it will probably not have significant phase shift at the frequencies below the unity gain point of the opamp.

Comment: @KevinWhite you are most likely right. However, when there is more than a simple low valued resistor in the opamp feedback path, I just always throw the cap there, to at least have a footprint in the final design for this cap.

Comment: @BarsMonster I added some more explanation and more precise wording and reasoning. I will still add some part number suggestions for opamp, and voltage reference.

Comment: It will be hard to achieve 25nVp-p with this design as the 12.5Ω resistor will act as a noise source with at least 200nVp-p (assuming 100kHz for the bandwidth and 25C). The bandwidth will need to be limited on the 12.5Ω resistor.

Comment: @VoltageSpike One could add a capacitor in parallel with the resistor, but it is not needed: the bandwidth on the resistor simply doesnt matter. It is important that none of this high frequency current flows through the diode. And this is accomplished via the double LC bypass explained in the section "Add in the laser diode"

Comment: @tobalt Thanks for detailed description! Few questions: 1) Could you draw proposed double-LC filtering circuit? I afraid there is a place for error (see comment #2)  2) Do you think it could make sense to have at least 1 small capacitor in parralel to D1, so that at very short timeframes it is voltage-stabilized, not current? Or it is a question that goes into photonics... Maybe it needs to be tested. 3) What do you think about MAX6126 which while having noise comparable to LTC6655, allows to directly implement current source via internal opamp?

Comment: @tobalt if one would try to average multiple parts - what could be beneficial: average 10 vref's or sum 10 current sources? I would assume if 10 current sources are summed - noise on vref+opamp would be averaged (reduced) vs just vref noise reduced. Combined noise on R1 is probably going to be the same....

Comment: @BarsMonster, using the integrated "opamp" in Refs with sense pin like MAX6126: I would not because it is not specced as well as a discrete part. Paralleling Vrefs or summing currents will reduce noise, but if you are going to such lengths, the effort is better spent on an ovenized discrete buried Zener like LM399 or LTZ1000. There are forums full of people trying to beat the LTZ, and the only way is by paralleling LTZ's ;-) I can draw the LC parts and update schematic, but probably only tomorrow.

Comment: @BarsMonster I added some details and schematic. My suggestion would be to try with a low voltage low noise bandgap reference and strong RC low pass first. e.g. the LTC6655 with 1.25 V and a low R1 of 6.25 Ohm. My noise calculations indicate that this will meet your specs. if noise will be too high still, you can try with an LTZ 7V reference, but would need a new R1 resistor.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the problem is attacked by providing transistors or FETs in parallel, selection of good components and stabilization and noise reduction of the supply voltage.

Solution1. Off the shelf, you can buy something like this http://www.sisyph.com/smc11-puy-mary-ultra-low-noise-current-source: source of 210 mA or 470 mA, RMS < 25 nA that fits almost your 50 nAp-p limit.

Solution2. An elaborated loop of stabilization and noise reduction of the drain voltage of FETs connected in parallel, accompanied by high-quality resistors placed on the source (R3 and R4) that determine the noise level above the corner frequency (50 mHz or so).
Note: the "corner frequency" divides the evident 1/f profile from the almost flat white noise region. A 50 mHz for many applications is equivalent to say that 1/f of this realization is non-existent, or not relevant. For laser diode, unless stability over 20 seconds or so is required, thee 50 mHz corner frequency is not influential.

See "Ultra Low-Noise Current Sources", 1998, doi:10.1109/19.728794.
The Conference version of the paper is available at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3089160_Ultra_low-noise_current_sources. I can provide a copy of the original paper, if needed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to reduce the Vp-p ripple, and if you don't care about the efficiency of the circuit, is to make a high voltage supply, 100-200VDC.

Assuming your diode is about 2V, The trick to reducing the ripple is that by increasing the voltage to ~200V, you can dump 198V (or about 99%) in a resistor, which in turn reduces the ripple a 100x.

With a target of 50nAp-p current at around 2V, this gives you a target of 10mVp-p
at 200V, which is much easier to achieve. The current is regulated by the resistor.

You can implement a capacitor multiplier coupled with other filtering methods on the 200V source and do a Voltage regulated supply with a 10mVp-p target, which is much easier to achieve.

Of course, this implementation has some downsides, efficiency is about 1%, which will require dissipating about 40W at 300mA.

Also, the resistor may vary regarding temperature, but the input voltage can be regulated in a closed-loop based on the current -> shunt + opamp to control the voltage level.

To cope with thermal dependency change of the resistor and thus variance in the current, several methods can be implemented:

Active regulation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f661Cd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This may introduce ripple, and thus needs to be filtered with slow filters. A method can be to use an MCU with digital filters and PID to then digitally control a power supply.

Passive regulation:
Another method is to regulate the temperature of the resistor, using a fan and thermometer for example, either by trigger or by PID.

If you don't really care about the absolute 300mA, but only the ripple, then simply wait for the resistor (and system in general) to thermally stabilize.

Comment: By using a low voltage control circuit of OA1, R3, R4 and R1 to regulate the high voltage, you are also gaining up the noise in the control circuit. And then you drop this noise again over R1. My gut feeling is, that in the end the performance will again hinge on the performance of the Opamp and the resistors.

Comment: The change of resistance by temperature is pretty slow, thus one can use very slow filters on the OA, in the order of several seconds (given the supply is capped) or even use a digital PID on an MCU with digital filters, the circuit will take some time to stabilize (5-20min) but should be more stable than a low voltage control. This has the advantage to be fairly easy to implement with an MCU and an oversized power supply that can be digitally, finely controlled.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I meant that when the low voltage circuitry works off ~10V and has a certain SNR in this voltage range, if you stear a 200 V source range with it, the SNR will stay the same. The only way to improve is if you use the 10 V control circuitry to stear a 190V fixed voltage + 10 V control range. But *then* who guarantees the stability of the 190 V ?

Comment: As the regulation doesn't need to be fast, you only need to keep the ~300mA, the deviation will only be related to heat variances on the resistor & diode, which at the start will be big but then very small once thermally stabilized. Thus one can implement very slow digital filters, which greatly eases the dealing of SNR since you average a lot of datapoints. PID can further help to bring the system to a stable point.

Comment: Also, you only need regulation if it needs to be exactly 300mA. If op doesn't care much about the absolute value, but only the ripple, a simple manual pot to adjust it is ok, then only need to wait for stabilization, perhaps temperature control of the resistors.

Comment: Thanks for innovative design!